# How can Valyrian steel kill White Walkers?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As shown in the last season of Game of Thrones, one of the leaders of the White Walkers was killed by Jon Snow's Valyrian steel sword.

As we know, White Walkers can be killed by Fire and Dragon Glass only.

Comment: The real-world equivalent of Valyrian steel is [Damascus steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damascus_steel); however, [there seems to be no real-world equivalent for White Walkers](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/06/19/westeros-europe_n_7565694.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a GoT forum...

> I think the major thing they both have in common is they both somewhat embody fire. Just like the Others of oure ice that will go through normal steel like nothing, therefore Valyrian steel or obsidian which is literally "frozen fire" to some degrees hold the opposite element to that of ice, and will destroy it.

http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/86855-confusing-dragon-glass-with-valyrian-steel/

Comment: In the books: Legends say Valyrian steel was forged with dragon-fire and infused with magical spells - some say with blood magic.